# node Undefined index

Tags: nodes

when a create a news content (exple article) I got this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 4 of /var/www/vhosts/elantechnology-bf.com/wapoparc/sites/all/themes/goodnex/templates/node/node--view--popular-posts--block.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 4 of /var/www/vhosts/elantechnology-bf.com/wapoparc/sites/all/themes/goodnex/templates/node/node--view--popular-posts--block.tpl.php).

I need your help to fix this

Comment: It would seem that in your `node--view--popular-posts--block.tpl.php` template file, you are referencing an incorrect array element (with the key of `und`). Can you show what you have in that template file?

Comment: This is an issue you should report in the [Goodnex support forum](http://refaktorthemes.com/support/forum/5), if that's the premium theme you bought.